# Retrieving Data From Three Table

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, sql

```
                cmd =new SqlCommand("Select i.InvoiceNo,i.TotalAmount,
                     i.PaymentStatus,m.MovieID,m.MovieName, s.CompanyName
                     From InvoiceDetails i INNER JOIN Movie m ON 
                     i.InvoiceNo=m.InvoiceNo and Supplier s 
                     Inner Join Movie m ON s.SupplierID=m.SupplierID 
                     Where SupplierID=@supplierID AND 
                     CompanyName=@companyName AND PaymentStatus=@ddlPaymentStatus",
                     conPayment);
```

This is the wrong Select Statement and How can I modify it in order successful to get the data from three table.

Comment: You should post your tables structure. Like this is hard to know where you went wrong

Comment: What do you mean by _this is wrong_? Syntax error? Not getting result as you want?

Comment: ya.just a syntax error.if two table I can successful to retrieve records, but three table I have no idea to retrieve it.

Comment: what is that syntax error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one thing that jumps out at me is one JOIN done incorrectly:

You have:

```sql
...
from InvoiceDetails i
inner join Movie m on i.InvoiceNo = m.InvoiceNo
  and Supplier s
inner join Movie m on s.SupplierID = m.SupplierID
...
```

It should be:

```sql
select i.InvoiceNo,i.TotalAmount,i.PaymentStatus,m.MovieID,m.MovieName,s.CompanyName
from InvoiceDetails i
inner join Movie m on i.InvoiceNo = m.InvoiceNo
inner join Supplier s on s.SupplierID = m.SupplierID
where s.SupplierID = @supplierID
  and s.CompanyName = @companyName
  and i.PaymentStatus = @ddlPaymentStatus
```

You already joined `Movie` once, you have to then JOIN on `supplier` also. The way you are doing it will surely give you a syntax error. Once for having two tables with the same alias, and then it would also complaint about not knowing supplier s, since it would be expecting a column from the tables joined before that.

Comment: Use `M.SupplierID = @supplierID` and you'll also likely need to preface CompanyName and PaymentStatus with whatever table alias is appropriate.

Comment: You have to prefix the column names with the table alias. in that case, s.supplierID, etc. i edited my answer.

Comment: Also, be sure to vote @FilipeSilva as the answer if he answered your question.

Comment: Thank @FilipeSilva for willing to help and solved my problem.